# How to Serialize CSR Matrix

Tags: python, json, serialization, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a `csr_matrix` objects calculate from `TfidfTransformer.transform`. I want to serialize or and unserialize:

```
tf_csrmtrix = TfidfTransformer.transform(data)
json.dumps(tf_csrmtrix)
TypeError: Object of type 'csr_matrix' is not JSON serializable
```

How can I work this king of data: csr matrices?

Comment: does it have to be JSON? or at all human-readable? or a binary serialization will do the trick?

Comment: should be binary/string serialized,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a binary serialization format will do the trick, I'll suggest the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump)

just `import pickle` and use `pickle.dumps` where you used `json.dumps` (notice this gives a bytes-object and not a string like json does)

you should be able to write to a file, a DB, or over some socket, and load it (using pickle) later, to get the exact same object